# Solving a simple convex optimization problem in low complexity

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, symmetric-matrices

Given a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I would like to solve the following maximization problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{t \in \mathbb{R}, \,\, x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{maximize}} & t\\ \text{subject to} & x^T A x \leq{} 1\\ & x_i \geq t, \quad \forall i \in \{1,2\dots,n\}\end{array}$$

I've find a solution to solve its dual problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}} & y^T A^{-1} y\\ \text{subject to} & 1^T y = 1\\ & y_i \geq 0, \quad \forall i \in \{1,2\dots,n\}\end{array}$$

However, to solve this problem, I need to calculate the matrix inverse of $A$, which requires large complexity. I wonder if there is a low complexity methods to solve the original convex optimization problem without doing full matrix size inverse?

---

Dual problem derivation:

1. Derive the Lagrangian: $$L(x,t,c,y) = -t + c(x^T A x-1) + \sum_i\{y_i(t-x_i)\}$$ where $c$ and $y$ are dual variables.
2. Formulate the KKT conditions:
   $\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{t}} = 1^Ty-1=0,\ \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{x}} = c(A+A^T)x-y=2cAx-y=0\\ c(x^TAx-1)=0,\ y_i(t-x_i) = 0\ \forall i \in \{1,2\dots,n\},\\ c\geq{0},\ y_i\geq{0}$
3. By the second equality in 2., we get $x=\frac{1}{2c}A^{-1}y$.
4. It is obviously that $c$ is not zero; otherwise, the first two equality will be violated. Therefore, by the third equality $x^TAx=1$.
5. Substitute $x$ in 3. into 4., we can finally get $c=\sqrt{\frac{x^TA^{-1}x}{4}}$.
6. It can be easily verify that the Slater's condition is satisfied, which means the dual gap is zero.
7. The dual problem is $$\max_{c,y}\{\min_{x,t}\{L(\cdot)\}\} = \cdots = \max \left\{ -\sqrt{y^TA^{-1}y} \right\}$$
8. By 2. & 7. we can get the dual problem fomulation.

Comment: I've updated the derivation of the dual problem.

Comment: Do you really need the dual? You can write the original maximization problem as a semidefinite program.

Comment: [Convex Optimization in Signal Processing and Communications](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511804458), Cambridge University Press, 2011.

Comment: Let $\rm A = R^\top R$ be a Cholesky decomposition. Hence, ${\rm x^\top A x} \leq 1$ can be rewritten as the following linear matrix inequality (LMI) $$\begin{bmatrix} {\rm I}_r & {\rm R x}\\ \rm{x^\top R^\top} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \succeq {\rm O}_{r+1}$$ where $r$ is the rank of $\rm A$.

Comment: You can't really escape the inversion. Even if you solve the primal problem using the simplest first-order method - Gradient Projection - you will still need in each step to project onto the feasible set which may be computationally expensive. Your dual representation actually allows an efficient projection onto the feasible set (unit simplex, can be projected in $O(n)$ time). And while inverting a matrix at each iteration is not great, there are pretty efficient implementations for that. Notice the nice primal-dual relation - hard project onto primal feasible set = hard dual inversion